# How to use AWS Redshift Data API to execute SQL using Java?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Can someone help me to get the exact code using Java & Redshift Data API to execute SQL?

We are going to create API in Spring Boot with Java where it will execute the SQL provided in request body. The backend will be Redshift. In this case, would like to use Redshift Data API to execute SQL instead of JDBCTemplate because of AWS provides good features like Async call, avoid DB connection pool etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform a SQL statement (without using the Java JDBC API), you can invoke the [executeStatement](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/redshiftdata/RedshiftDataClient.html#executeStatement-software.amazon.awssdk.services.redshiftdata.model.ExecuteStatementRequest-) method and specify a SQL statement (for example - a CREATE statement), using the [ExecuteStatementRequest object's sql method](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/redshiftdata/model/ExecuteStatementRequest.html#sql--).

Here is an example of running a SQL statement using the Redshift Data API that creates a table named **work1**.

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.DynamoDbClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.redshiftdata.RedshiftDataClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.redshiftdata.model.ExecuteStatementRequest;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.redshiftdata.model.ExecuteStatementResponse;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.redshiftdata.model.RedshiftDataException;

public class CreateTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String clusterIdentifier = "redshift-items";
        String dataBase = "dev";
        String user = "root";

        String sqlStatement = "CREATE TABLE work1(\n" +
                "    idwork VARCHAR(45) PRIMARY KEY,\n" +
                "    date Date,\n" +
                "    description VARCHAR(400),\n" +
                "    guide VARCHAR(45),\n" +
                "    status VARCHAR(400),\n" +
                "    username VARCHAR(45),\n" +
                "    archive BOOLEAN\n" +
                ")  ;";

        Region region = Region.US_EAST_1;
        RedshiftDataClient redshiftDataClient = RedshiftDataClient.builder()
                .region(region)
                .build();

    try {
        ExecuteStatementRequest statementRequest = ExecuteStatementRequest.builder()
               .clusterIdentifier(clusterIdentifier)
                .dbUser(user)
                .database(dataBase)
                .sql(sqlStatement)
                .build();

        ExecuteStatementResponse resp = redshiftDataClient.executeStatement(statementRequest);
        System.out.println("The query id is " +resp.id());

    } catch (RedshiftDataException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }

}
}
```

This worked and i can view the table in the Redshift console:

[image]

For the Java Data API V2, ensure you add this dependency to the POM file (if you are using a Gradle file, convert this to Gradle):

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>redshiftdata</artifactId>
   </dependency>
```

***For this example, the creds are located in a credential file located at C:\Users\USERNAME.aws\credentials on Windows.***

Comment: Basically, I am trying with below gradle to use Async Redshift Data API:
     compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-redshiftdataapi', version: '1.11.934'

I am unable to understand, how should I authenticate to use the redshift data api?